# Why does my query to array return an array of objects in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to simply run a query and get the results in an array:

```
function run_query($query)
{
    $out = '';
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test","test","test");
    $out = $db->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $out;
}
```

And on the other end:

```
$l_o_array = $php_functions->run_query('SHOW TABLES');
$temp = implode(',', $l_o_array);
```

> Result: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

I assume this is because I use `FETCH_OBJ`, but what do I use to just get an array of strings?

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` will fetch an array of arrays as you are using `fetchAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you might do it:

```
function run_query($query)
{
    $out = '';
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test","test","test");
    $out = $db->query($query)->fetchAll();
    return $out;
}

$results = run_query('SHOW TABLES');

$tables = array();
foreach($results as $result)
    $tables[] = $result['Tables in test']; // Note, replace "test" with your database name

$temp = implode(',', $tables);
```

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically build the array in the function. I want it to be able to handle something as simple as 'Show Tables', but also something more complex like 'SELECT * FROM foo' where foo may have multiple columns and rows.

Comment: In order to get an "array of strings" you must iterate the results (which is an array of arrays) and pull out the relevant column. If you're okay with an array of arrays, you simply need to return the result of `fetchAll()`. Make sense?

Comment: OK, this is what I have now, but metadata doesn't work with PDO. Any suggestions?
`function run_query($query)
  {
   $out = '';
   $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test","test","test");
   $out    = $db  -> query($query);
   $md     = $out -> result_metadata();
   $out    = $out -> fetchAll();
   $fields = $md  -> fetch_fields();
   $tables = array();
   foreach ($fields as $field)
    foreach($results as $result)
     $tables[] = $result[$field];

   return $tables;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

try print_R();

to under stand the proplem

```
<?php
$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
print_r ($a);
?>
```

regard's